# key error when trying to split two entries in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a dictionary with entries that have the ip and ports displayed like this

`{'source': '192.168.4.1:80', 'destination': '168.20.10.1:443'}`

but i want it to display it like

```
{'src_ip': '192.168.4.1', 'src_port': 80, 'dest_ip': '168.20.10.1', 'dest_port': 443}
```

so i want to split the first two entries into 4 new ones and delete the two old ones.
my code currently looks like this:

```
log entry = {'source': '192.168.4.1:80', 'destination': '168.20.10.1:443'}


def split_ip_port(log_entry):

   u_source = log_entry['source']
   if ':' in u_source:
       src_list = u_source.split(':')
       src_ip = src_list[0]
       src_port = src_list[1]
       log_entry.update({'src_ip': src_ip})
       log_entry.update({'src_port': src_port})
       del log_entry['source']
    
   u_dest = log_entry['destination']
   if ':' in u_dest:
       dest_list = u_dest.split(':')
       dest_ip = dest_list[0]
       dest_port = dest_list[1]
       print(dest_list)
       log_entry.update({'dest_ip': dest_ip})
       log_entry.update({'dest_port': dest_port})
       del log_entry['destination']
   return log_entry
```

when i try to test the source it gives me keyerror :'destination' and when i try to test the destination it gives me keyerror source. what is happening here?

Comment: After some indentation, your code prints `{'src_ip': '192.168.4.1', 'src_port': '20', 'dest_ip': '168.20.10.1', 'dest_port': '443'}` so it seems like it should work.

Comment: I'm guessing you are calling the function a second time? or you remove one of the keys from the dictionary before testing it?

Comment: the error tells me that when it wants to run the destination part of the code it stops at the line '''u_source = log_entry['source']''' and gives me keyError: source

Comment: @wkl I also fixed the ident and run the snippet, seems to be working at least on python 3.9

Comment: could it be due to my interpreter settings?

Comment: Is this code snippet as-is from your editor/text file/etc. and everything you did to call the method? It does have some issues (like `log entry` at the top needing the `_`) and needs from proper indentation. Can you show us how you're calling the method?

Comment: @wkl i used a new interpreter and it now wroks for me. the code did have some minor issues but those were due to the copy-paste. my code in the editor was working without error after using new interpreter.

Comment: i dont know what was going wrong with the old one. and why i would get a keyerror

Comment: @blaker1327 it seems to be working fine. No error.  But the code could be simplified a bit.  Use dictionary key/value.

Answer (score 1):

When you split value (e.g., `log_entry['source'].split(":")` ) it returns `list ['192.168.4.1','80']`. Then you have to return value by index from `list, [0]` index in list is '192.168.4.1'. Then you have to assign it to new key in your dict, `log_entry['src_ip']`

```
log_entry['src_ip']  = log_entry['source'].split(":")[0]
log_entry['src_port'] = log_entry['source'].split(":")[1]
log_entry['dest_ip'] = log_entry['destination'].split(":")[0]
log_entry['dest_port'] = log_entry['destination'].split(":")[1]
del log_entry['source']
del log_entry['destination']
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable answer. Could you add a sentence or two about what you're doing? The explanation would improve your answer.

Comment: when you split value for example: log_entry['source'].split(":")  it returns list ['192.168.4.1','80'] then you have to return value by index from list,  [0] index in list is '192.168.4.1' then you have to assign it to new key in your dict, log_entry['src_ip']  =

Comment: It seems the repeated steps can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original code work. Here just an offer to simplify the original code - you could try to split the source/destination and ports then just create a *new* dictionary like this way:

```
orig_dc = {'source': '192.168.4.1:80', 'destination': '168.20.10.1:443'}

new_dc = {}

for k, v in orig_dc.items():
    orig, port = v.split(':')

    if k in 'source':
        new_dc.setdefault('src_ip', orig)
        new_dc.setdefault('src_port', int(port))
    else:
        new_dc.setdefault('dest_ip', orig)
        new_dc.setdefault('dest_port', int(port))
    
    

expected = { 'src_ip': '192.168.4.1', 'src_port': 80,
             'dest_ip': '168.20.10.1', 'dest_port': 443}
             

assert new_dc == expected
```